# How does the preg_replace () function work in php?

Tags: php, regex

I have a string `ryyyr #rrrr iituut iit #Google rrr #Tom65`

In this string I am looking for all tags by regex `/^#[A-Za-zА-Яа-я0-9_]{4,20}/`

And I want to replace all found tags with the word penis, But for some reason nothing works

```
public static function findHashTags () {       
    $string = 'ryyyr #rrrr iituut iit #Google rrr #Tom65';
    $pattern = '/^#[A-Za-zА-Яа-я0-9_]{4,20}/';
    $replacement = 'penis';
    $a = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
    return $a;
}
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_regex.asp

Comment: Apart from the misplaced anchor, Unicode chars need an additional flag to match.

Answer (score 0):

In your regex you have `^`, it just strings with `#` at the beginning passed.

Regex you're looking for is

```
/#[A-Za-zА-Яа-я0-9_]{4,20}/
```

Or another variant is shorter (isn't exact equivalent, I mean it'll do the work for you too).

```
#\S{4,20}
```